# Do some Windows Messages have higher priority than others?

Tags: winapi

I am not sure if "priority" is the correct term, but this is what I mean:

Windows Messages are placed in the message queue, and then they are dequeued by `GetMessage()` on a FIFO basis.

My question is: does Windows place some Messages as the first item in the message queue, or are all Messages placed in the last position?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but this definitely contradicts the obligations when using a FIFO.

Comment: The queue is first in first out. But some messages are low priority and are synthesised when you call GetMessage. If there are no messages in the queue, WM_TIMER and WM_PAINT messages may be synthesised at that point.